# Calculus- Definite Integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Suppose that
>   $$\int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx=5$$
>   $$\int_{1}^4 f(x)dx=-2$$
>   $$\int_{-1}^4 h(x)dx=7$$
>   Find the value of
>   $$\int_{-1}^4 (2f(x)+3h(x))dx$$

I understand how to find definite and indefinite integrals, but I'm not entirely sure how to even begin this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Recall that
$$\int_a^b g(x)dx+\int_b^c g(x)dx=\int_a^c g(x)dx$$
for any function $g$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Recall that

$$\int_{-1}^4 (2f(x)+3h(x))dx=2\int_{-1}^4 f(x)dx+3\int_{-1}^4 h(x)dx$$

and

$$\int_{-1}^4 f(x)dx=\int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx+\int_{1}^4 f(x)dx$$

Comment: @JackyChong Please keep meta comments to meta.